# Writing a while loop in my Python program

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a problem with my code. I want to loop code as long as in cargo are still any items. and print: box1 [items], box2 [items] box3 [items].

```
 cargo = [41,20,4,5,30,2,7,3,19,32,40,20,35,15,32,19]
print("number of itmes: ",len(cargo))
cargo.sort()
cargo.reverse()
print("list of imtems in cargo: ", cargo)
boxCapacity = 90;
box = []
i = 0

while i<len(cargo) and (boxCapacity - sum(box)) >= min(cargo):
    if (boxCapacity- sum(box)) >= cargo[i]:
        box.append(cargo[i])
    i+=1
print("sum of taken items: ",sum(box))
print("items taken: ", box)
for i in box:
    cargo.remove(i)
    if i==0:
        break
print("items left in cargo: box",cargo)
```

Comment: Unless I am missing the point, I see multiple difficulties in the code. I would start by creating "manually" the final results of boxes and cargo and first ensure I was able to print them properly. Only afterwards I'd start working on the actual code of moving from cargo to box.

Comment: thanks for answer, the final result can looks every time diferent, because the list of cargo will be diferent everytime. the point is that the cargo iteams must be placed in boxes in a way to leave as little as possible space. in this code space is 90.

Comment: I understand that. But you can create an example in a sheet of paper, and work out what the final printed results should look like. If you do that, how does that compare with the prints from running the code?

Comment: "expected result" vs "obtained results by running the code"

Comment: Right now, you are creating only one box and once it is full your code stops. From what I understand, when that happens you want to start a new box and fill that up. So if that's the case, your while loop should not include the box capacity just whether you have items left in your cargo list. You need to start a new box when the box is full and keep going, filling the new box.